# Передать в Activity id выбранной записи из списка

Tags: android, recyclerview

Есть активити `FirstActivity`. В ней есть текстовое поле нажав на которую открывается второе активити `SecondActivity`. В `SecondActivity` есть список `RecyclerView` с категориями. Как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на какой-то из элементов списка `id` объекта, который выводится в этой позиции передавался в `FirstActivity`?

Допустим в `SecondActivity` выводятся две категории:

```
1. id = 1, name = "Категория № 1"
2. id = 2, name = "Категория № 2"
```

Например при нажатии на "Категория № 1" закрывать `SecondActivity` и передавать id = 2 в `FirstActivity`

Вот мой адаптер

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.CategoryViewHolder> {

    private List<Category> categoryList;
    private Context mContext;

    OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int categoryID, String categoryName);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    public CategoryAdapter(Context context, List<Category> categoryList){
        this.categoryList = categoryList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public class CategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public RoundedImageView imgCategory;
        public CheckedTextView txtCategory;


        public CategoryViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtCategory = (CheckedTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCategory);
            imgCategory = (RoundedImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgCategory);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mItemClickListener.onItemClick(categoryList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId(), categoryList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.category_item,parent,false);
        CategoryViewHolder vh = new CategoryViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final Category category = categoryList.get(position);
        holder.txtCategory.setText(category.getName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return categoryList.size();
    }

}
```

Category.class

```
@Entity()
public class Category {
   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Category(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

SecondActivity

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CategoryAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    private RecyclerView rvCategory;
    private CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    private int SELECT_CATEGORY_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        rvCategory = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvCategory);

        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,1);
        rvCategory.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        CookBookDB db = AppDatabase.getInstance().getCookBookDB(); 
        CategoryDao categoryDao = db.categoryDao();

        categoryDao.getAllCategories().observe(this, (List<Category> categoryList) -> {
            categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(SecondActivity.this, categoryList);
            categoryAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            rvCategory.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int categoryID, String categoryName) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("categoryID", categoryID);
        intent.putExtra("categoryName", categoryName);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_CATEGORY_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

FirstActivity

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int SELECT_CATEGORY_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_recipe);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case SELECT_CATEGORY_REQUEST:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    System.out.println(data.getStringExtra("categoryName"));

                }
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Пытаюсь сделать таким образом но данные не передаются в FirstActivity

Comment: А в SecondActivity вы их получаете из колбэка адаптера?

Comment: Да из адаптера.

Comment: Если в SecondActivity вы их получаете, а в FirstActivity они не приходят, то нужен код получения интента в FirstActivity.

Comment: Я бы вам посоветовал почитать про onActivityResult и использовать его для SecondActivity, так будет самое правильное решение. И проверьте например логами, у вас данные приходят в second Activity.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: для того, чтобы колбэк onActivityResult() сработал, нужно закрывать текущее активити через finish() с setResult(), а не вызовом нового активити

Comment: Спасибо) получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал так:

```
    public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CategoryAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

        ***

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_category);

            ***
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int categoryID, String categoryName) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("categoryID", categoryID);
            intent.putExtra("categoryName", categoryName);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            this.finish();
        }

    }

public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int SELECT_CATEGORY_REQUEST = 3;

    private int categoryID;
    private String categoryName = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_recipe);

        ***
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        txtCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_CATEGORY_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case SELECT_CATEGORY_REQUEST:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    categoryID = data.getIntExtra("categoryID", 0);
                    categoryName = data.getStringExtra("categoryName");
                }
                break;
        }

    }

}
```